# Libgdx What TextureAtlas filter should I use?

Tags: filter, libgdx, texture-atlas

What filter should I use for a TextureAtlas?(Linear/Nearest)...
This is my current setting in the atlas file:

```
filter: Linear,Linear
```

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. They're all useful in different ways.

Comment: I want good performance(for Android) and good Quality

Comment: I suggest you to read this [article](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1403)

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to use pot(2^n) Textures?(Will this affect the performance?)

Comment: You should not worry too much about performance in the early stage. But yes you should use pot2 textures. If you don't LibGDX will make them for you and you waste space.

Comment: Okay. When I add Textures that aren't pot to TexturePacker and set "size constraints" to "POT" will it count as pot? If I add Textures that ARE pot to TexturePacker, do I need to check "POT" in "size constraints"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filters rather do not have big impact to performance (when we tell about small sprites) although there are some serious differences between them.

In practice [Filters](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Filter.html) describe how edge of texture is being processed

- *Linear* - will do edges smooth but it is possible that it will be producing some weird artifacts on connections between tiles of element created from many smaller sprites - also can cause problems with big textures
- *Nearest* - will do edges sharp which will be very bad for some circles
- *MipMap* - connects pros of Linear and Nearest but will need more space for many versions of sprite

Take a look at [this great article](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1403) that @Enigo reccomends you to get more information.